# Google Analytics tracking code with User-ID

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I am trying to get the User-ID feature to work within Google Analytics.  In order to do this, I have to pass a PHP variable to Google Analytics using JavaScript.

I have attempted to do this by echoing all of the Javascript in a PHP script.

Here is that script:

```html
<?php

if (isset($username)) {

    echo "\n";   
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
 echo "(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');\n";
 echo "ga('create', 'UA-********-1', 'auto');\n";
 echo "ga('set', 'userID', '" . $username . "');\n";
 echo "ga('send', 'pageview');\n";
 echo "</script>\n";

} else {

    echo "\n";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
 echo "(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');\n";
 echo "ga('create', 'UA-********-1', 'auto');\n";
 echo "ga('send', 'pageview');\n";
 echo "</script>\n";
}
?>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2015-12-03**

I have decided to use a more direct method to test whether or not the user is logged-in, and also, I've combined the different echoes into one for each leg of the conditional statement:

```
<?php

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {

echo "<!-- Google Analytics with userId -->
<script>
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'userId', '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->";
} else {
echo "<!-- Google Analytics with pageview only -->
<script>
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'userId', '" . 'anonymous' . "');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->";
}
?>
```

This new snippet works.  Note though that I had to set `userId` in order for the  code in the else statement to work.  It must be the case that you have to set `userId` if you enable user tracking in Google Analytics.  I have not verified that yet, but it does seem like a reasonable inference.

Comment: `var_dump($username);` and see if it actually contains any data.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMcGready.  As you suspected, the $username variable = NULL, but shouldn't the code in the ELSE statement be executed in that case?  For instance, var_dump(isset($username)) = bool(false).

Comment: It depends. If `$username` is set to `NULL` it may still fire the first condition as `$username` is technically set although it's value is `NULL`. What to do is dump 2 `echo` statements in each block - one with `echo 'username is set';` and `echo 'username is not set';` and see what outputs. Then you can debug further from that

Comment: @ScottMcGready ... Thanks again.  I'll try that approach for now on.

Comment: Change the condition to `if(isset($username) && $username !== NULL){`

Comment: @ScottMcGready ... Thinking about how to test if the conditional was working definitely helped me figure out that I had to set `userId` in the else statement in order for this code to work.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. It's worth looking up the docs on assignment operators as there's a big difference between `=`, `==`, and `===`. That might clarify it a bit for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name for the User ID parameter that you are using is not correct. It should be `userId` (camel case), but you are using `userID`. Also, make sure you have the User ID feature enabled from the GA interface.